Use same font in inkscape as in latex
I am writing a paper in LaTex and I am using sans-serif font both for text and math. I need to generate png images to illustrate the paper and many images requires text. I like to use inkscape. How can I proceed in order to have the same fonts in inkscape as I load in LaTeX?
These are the lines of code in my LaTeX to set the text and math fonts:
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet} %... sets text font to helvetica
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{newtxsf}        %... sans serif math symbols
\usepackage{isomath}        %... handles mathrm to match text font (?)


png isn't such a good choice if the image contains text. It won't be accessible for screen readers and people can't search for the text in the article. Instead, use a vector format like pdf, export from inkscape as pdf+tex and you will automatically get the correct fonts when you include the graphic in your article.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you for the comment. I really need to generate a figure, not a .pdf_tex file. Figure can either be in png, jpg or pdf...

Why can't you use a .pdf_tex if you are going to include it in an article?

(1) Because I really don't know how to generate it nor how to include it in latex -- I really tried and read a lot of websites, but always get compilation errors; it may seem very simple, but I never get the result. (2) I don't konow how to open such a file in other context -- I mean, what kind of software opens such an image if I share just the .pdf_tex file?

Ok, that sounds like problems we can solve :) Let me look for an old answer of mine in which I have a step by step guide how to create a .pdf_tex

See this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469754/adding-latex-to-figures-from-inkscape/469759#469759

The .pdf_tex isn't really an image. You will get a normal .pdf of the same name in addition to it which contains the image (just without the text). The .pdf_tex file is actually just a tex file with a different name. The same editor with which you edit your latex document should also be able to open it (but normally, you shouldn't need to open it).

The big advantage of using a .pdf_tex file is that the text in your image won't just have the same font as your article, the text will also have the same size.

I had already seen your post at the link you shared here. I always use overleaf and still get the erros. I just tested in a blank project and it worked. So, I have to figure out what is the problem with my code. Thank  you @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
